# Simple IF/ELSEIF not comparing properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm new to PHP and this was asked before but the answers just won't cut it in my scenario.

I have this piece of code:

```
  if ($node->field_available_for_payment[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']==0){
  }  elseif($node->field_available_for_payment[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']==1){
     $status="awaitingapproval";
  }  elseif (3===3){
     $status="paid";
  } elseif ($node->field_shipped[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']==1){
     $status="shipped";
  } 

 var_dump($status);
```

I get back value *awaitingapproval* (the first `if/elseif` evaluate to
**TRUE**).

However shouldn't I be getting back '*paid*' instead since the 3===3 comparison evaluates to **TRUE**?

as well?

All the other S.0 answers regarding this type of questions mention the '=' operator vs '==' which is correct in my code.

Comment: What is `var_dump($node->field_available_for_payment[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);`? If it is `false`, `0`, `''` or `null` then that is the only IF condition that will be evaluated because those `==` 0.

Comment: @kingkero so should I swap this for a `SWITCH` instead?

Comment: No it should not because if (first_statement_is_true) dosomething ELSE (if do something). `else` here is keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control structures like if/else stop executing once a truthy statement is reached. Since the first block is true the other blocks are never evaluated.

If that first block should ever fail, (i.e. evaluate to false) then your second statement will always evaluate to true and the code will be executed.